# VS Code not detecting Python3 interpreter on MacOS

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, python-3.6, macos-high-sierra

I just upgrade python3 to 3.6 (using homebrew) and now VS Code doesn't seem to be aware of it. When I try to select my Python interpreter I see 2.7.9 and 2.7.10 (in `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin` respectively) but I do not see 3.6.3 (`/usr/local/bin/python3`).

It's certainly in my path, and I'm aware that I can update `settings.json` manually, but I use both Python 2 and 3 for various projects and making them available via the interpreter switcher would be incredibly useful. Any ideas why Code isn't autodetecting `python3`? Or is there a way for me to force-add it to the list?

Comment: What do you mean by 'when I try to select my Python interpreter'? Select how? The for settings vs code itself are the most reliable way to specify the interpreter you want.

Comment: @pvg - when I use the command palette or the toolbar to select a Python executable environment, it simply wasn't showing all my Python executables (from `/usr/local/bin`, for example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out. Something I clearly installed had modified by `.bash_profile` to include the following:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

I commented that out, restarted Code, and now I can see all my Python interpreters listed (including 3.6.3).

Comment: I'll note that the above entry in my `.bash_profile` was added by a package setup script. My guess is that Code was looking at that location, found no other Python binaries other than 2.7, and just stopped looking in other `$PATH` folders.

Answer (score 3):

In VS Code, you're able to easily set the interpreter you'd like to use for Python. Follow this official [guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).

From the site:

> To select a specific interpreter, select the Python: Select Interpreter command from the Command Palette (⇧⌘P).